# Turn by turn navigation embedded in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, mapbox, turn-by-turn

I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox which is a working fork for this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation.

It works great in full screen, but in embedded mode (using the map as a widget inside flutter, I can resize and put other widgets in top of it) it does not start navigation mode (turn by turn).

I can even hear the sound of navigation, but the map remains in free drive mode (explorer mode).

The package we are working on is https://github.com/fabiolin/mapbox-demo

The bug occurs when calling startnavigation().

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.